# Migrating Azure Table storage

Tags: mongodb, azure, ravendb, azure-table-storage, nosql

I have a cloud native app based on azure. The app uses azure table storage.

Due to a fantastic opportunity I have decided to also provide the app on-premises. So I have to replace the NoSql data provider... my question is: Which solution is more alike Azure Table Storage? Mongo? Raven? you name it!

What I intend is to migrate the code effortlessly, like migrating from SQL Azure to Sql Server 2012... no code change needed... but I know that theres no equivalent for table storage... so I intend to find the one that will reduce my TTM as much as possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB and Table Storage are not exactly swappable replacements for each other. One is key/value, the other is document. I compared the two in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14758781/272109).

There's no getting around the fact that Table Storage is Storage-as-a-Service and you only pay for quantity of data (plus a very small per-transaction cost), whereas to work with MongoDB, you'd either have to host it in your own VMs (which gives you plenty of storage room, but at the expense of VMs) or work with a hoster (such as MongoLab, which offers 500MB for free currently). Regardless, you'd have do do some code changes to work with MongoDB over Table Storage.

I'm not sure if there exists a key/value store equivalent to Table Storage that's locally-installable. No matter what you pick, you'll have modifications on your Azure-side solution if you swap out Table Storage.

Is it possible, for your on-premises solution, to provide a MongoDB backend that stays relatively simple? That is: Stick with a single index to substitute for rowkey, and then store your table entities as documents (avoiding sub-documents)? This would keep your data layout very similar. At that point, you *could* use things like Aggregation Framework for a bit of data processing, and not damage the overall layout style/schema of your data.

Comment: interesting... interesting indeed... I've been noticing that MS has been releasing on-premises version of "cloud systems" (SQL Server 2012 for Sql Azure... Service Bus for Windows Server... AppFabric Cache... etc...) maybe we will get a table storage also...

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB would give you a consistent storage framework that you could use in-cloud and on-premises, and has good support for Windows Azure.

Comment: my app already uses table storage... mongodb on the cloud would require at least 2 more VMs/Instances running (accounting for high-availability) which I can't afford right now...